# I have two differents components with only a navbar in common, but when I click in a link, a list keeps in both components but I update it in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I'm working in a project based in Angular and Firebase. I have a profile component, gallery, users and others. But I have also a problem.

In navbar I have the main menu to navigate between pages. Two importants in this case is:

1. Profile
2. Gallery

In Profile I show the publications posted by a User (any user profiles and publications). When I navigate to this page, the first thing I do is charge the publications by a user and I use an ngFor to iterate and show them.

In Gallery I show all the publications stored in Firebase. Gallery is also the main page when I login into the web. I charged all the publications and also show them using a ngFor loop.

Well, the problem is the next:
When I login, all the photos are shown in gallery. All is ok. I navigate to a profile (mine or any user) and page load the photos upload by that user. Now, I navigate again to Gallery (with or without pass for any other route) and, although I have in ngOnInit load all the photos, gallery page and ngFor iterate the publications that were shown in User Profile, and not loads all of them.

I even use two differents services for anyone, so reference is different. Any help? Add code to show the problem:

**HTML Gallery**

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <div id="showResultList" class="row mt-5">

        
        <app-loading-spinner  *ngIf="page.loading | async"></app-loading-spinner>

        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" id='megustanlaspapas' loading="lazy" *ngFor="let pub of page.data | async">
            <app-card-publication [pubR]='pub'></app-card-publication>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="loadMore" *ngIf='!loadAll' class="row mt-2 mb-3"> 
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" (click)='loadMore()'>
            <i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i> Cargar Más
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Gallery Component ngOnInit**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, public page : ScrollPaginationPublicationsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.loadAll = false;
     this.page.reset();
     this.page.init('publications', 'date');
  }
```

**Component Used in Gallery**
It search in Firestore Database using some attributtes. Nothing special really.

**HTML Profile**

```
<div class="tab-pane conf fade text-center" id="v-pills-myGraffitis" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-myGraffitis-tab">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let pubU of pubList">
                <app-card-publication [pubR]='pubU'></app-card-publication>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Profile Component**

```
constructor(private ps: PublicationsService) { }

this.ps.getUserPublications(this.user.uid).subscribe( 
  data => { this.pubList = data; }
);
```

**Service Used In Profile**
Different, but with the same functions with some changes to search.

Thanks.
I hope help.

[Gallery1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrAsj.png)

[Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Or1T.png)

[Gallery2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bres.png)

**UPDATE**

I detect where the error is caused.
In the Service used in Profile I make a search in 'publications' collection in Firebase. I take docs using valueChanges and a pipe. This:

```
  getUserPublications(uid: string): Observable<any> {
return this.fs.collection(this.path, ref => ref.where('uid', '==', uid.toString()))
.valueChanges()
.pipe( map(c => c) );
```

}

this.path its 'publications'.

Then in the service used in Gallery I have the next code:

```
private mapAndUpdate(col: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>) {

  // Map snapshot with doc ref (needed for cursor)
  return col.snapshotChanges()
    .do(arr => {
      let values = arr.map(snap => {
        const data = snap.payload.doc.data()
        const doc = snap.payload.doc
        return { ...data, doc };
      })
      console.log(values);
```

That console.log prints in console the list take in the first query used in Profile. I already know that error is there, but I don't know how to solve it. For some reason it not updates with the new query. I suppose that is due to valueChanges / snapshotChanges combination, but I don't know how to solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... WELL. I finally have fixed the problem. Error was that if I make a x.valueChanges(), AngularFirestore module keeps subscribe to them until the final of the world, although the component had been destroyed.

Solution?

Unsubscribe the valueChanges making a ngOnDestroy method like next:

```
s : any;

constructor(private afs : AngularFirestore){}

getPubs() {
    this.s = this.afs.collection('pubs')...;
}

ngOnDestroy(){
   this.s.unsubscribe();
}
```

And this is all. I hope it helps someone in the future.